# Connecting edge of Shape1 to edge of Shape2 Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have two shapes, shape1 and shape2. How do I connect the first shape to the edge of the second shape? i.e. I want the edge of shape1 to be perfectly inline to the edge of shape2, so that when I scale up or down they don't separate.

[image]

End product to look like below.

[image]

Very new to Inkscape. Did a couple of googles and didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi! I think your question is better suited for [graphic design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). SO is for programming.
That said, you may have a look at snapping and path operations in the online documentation.

Comment: Use snapping: https://inkscape.org/en/~Moini/%E2%98%85snapping-guide-091

Comment: @Moini the link is unreachable for me.

Comment: It's a temporary outage, @K.Moore - but here you go: https://vektorrascheln.de/posts/2016/Feb/snapping-guide-for-inkscape-0-91.html